# Check Array Before Element When Push Element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array  ( key, startValue , EndValue);

```
var fruits = [[1,10, 15], [1,25, 30]];
```

i want to Validate before Push

```
console.log(push([1,5, 35]));  // false
console.log(push([2,5, 35]));  // true
console.log(push([1,30, 40])); // true
console.log(push([1,15, 25])); // true
console.log(push([1,5, 10]));  // true

console.log(fruits);
```

Similarly i have key 2,3,4,5, ect.

i am working with below Script.

```
function push(array) {
    return fruits.every(function(a) {
        return array[0] == a[0] && (array[2] <= a[1] || a[2] <= array[1]);
    }) && fruits.push(array) && true;
}
```

Comment: My script is work only for startValue , EndValue, not for Key.

Comment: why is that `console.log(push([2,5, 35]));  // true` `true`?

Comment: Thank for respond, Not Now, it should come True.

Comment: is my approach is correct .?

Comment: oh that's what you want ? `console.log(push([2,5, 35])); ` you want this to be true instead of false ?

Comment: what should happen with the key if not equal?

Comment: if key is not Equal then Enter value in array, i want to compare key also

Comment: `fruits.every` will only iterate first array in `fruits ` . use forEach and then use every

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for the keys first.

```
return array[0] !== a[0] || array[2] <= a[1] || a[2] <= array[1];
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function push(array) {
    return fruits.every(function(a) {
        return array[0] !== a[0] || array[2] <= a[1] || a[2] <= array[1];
    }) && fruits.push(array) && true;
}

var fruits = [[1, 10, 15], [1, 25, 30]];

console.log(push([1, 5, 35]));  // false
console.log(push([2, 5, 35]));  // true
console.log(push([1, 30, 40])); // true
console.log(push([1, 15, 25])); // true
console.log(push([1, 5, 10]));  // true
console.log(push([2, 0, 5]));   // true
console.log(fruits);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```